# Media Player stop working /crushes after multiple clicks

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm creating an Android application that contains buttons, where clicking on each button play a mp3 file.

Problems are:

- No sound is played when I hit the buttons
- When I hit the buttons multiple times the media player stop working.

Code:

```
package com.example.puddly;

import android.animation.ObjectAnimator;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.view.animation.BounceInterpolator;
import android.widget.Button;

public class GameActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    Button btnDonkey,btnHorse,btnDog,btnFrog,btnChicken,btnCow,btnPig,btnDuck,btnCat;
    MediaPlayer mp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

    btnCat=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCat);
    btnDonkey=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMonkey);
    btnHorse=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnElephent);
    btnDog=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDog);
    btnFrog=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnFrog);
    btnChicken=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChicken);
    btnCow=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnCow);
    btnPig=(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnPig);
    btnDuck=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLion);
    btnHorse.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDog.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnFrog.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnChicken.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCow.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnPig.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDuck.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnDonkey.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnCat.setOnClickListener(this);
}



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnCat:
            ObjectAnimator animY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(btnCat, "translationY", -100f, 0f);
            animY.setDuration(1000);//1sec
            animY.setInterpolator(new BounceInterpolator());
            animY.setRepeatCount(0);
            animY.start();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.catname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);


            break;
        case R.id.btnMonkey:
               Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_rotate);
              v.startAnimation(animRotate);
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.monkeyname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);


            break;
        case R.id.btnElephent:
               Animation animTranslate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_translate);
            v.startAnimation(animTranslate);
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.elephantname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);

            break;
        case R.id.btnDog:
               Animation animAlpha = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_alpha);
            v.startAnimation(animAlpha);
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.dogname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);

            break;
        case R.id.btnFrog:
               Animation animScale = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_scale);
            v.startAnimation(animScale);
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.frogname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);

            break;
        case R.id.btnCow:
               Animation animScale2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_scale);
            v.startAnimation(animScale2);

            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.cowname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);

            break;
        case R.id.btnChicken:
               Animation animScale3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_scale);
            v.startAnimation(animScale3);

            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.chickenname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);

            break;
        case R.id.btnPig:
               Animation animScale4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_scale);
            v.startAnimation(animScale4);

            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.pigname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);

            break;
        case R.id.btnLion:
               Animation animScale5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
                        R.anim.anim_scale);
            v.startAnimation(animScale5);

            mp=MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.lionname);
            mp.start();
            mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);

            break;
}
    }
    }
```

Comment: are you following the life cycle of media player .. ? refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html

Comment: only certain number of mediaplayer instances can be used at a time.. it is impossible to have so many number of media player instances .. if your sound file length is small try using soundpool instead of media player

Comment: Also, if the app crashes post the logcat so we can see the exception.

Comment: @ofir are you playing small sounds ?

Comment: @ghost talker ye it's between 1-2 seconds for each sound

Comment: ok I am posting answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be helpful to you as you said that the sound are of 2 to 3 seconds. then consider using Soundpool in this case . [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html) you can read more about it.

And [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/android-soundpool-example/) Example would help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you have a bad design approach. You shouldnt create a new instance of MediaPlayer everytime you want to play a new track. Instead, create a single MediaPlayer in your `onCreate()` with the new operator. Then, when the user clicks a button, first `reset()`the mp, then `setDataSource()`, then `prepare()` and finally `start()`playing. Should work

`case R.id.btnMonkey:
        Animation animRotate = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
        R.anim.anim_rotate);
        v.startAnimation(animRotate);
        mp.reset();
        mp.setDataSource("Your mp3 file source here");
        mp.prepare();
        mp.start();
        mp.setVolume(0.5F, 0.5F);`

In your `onCreate()` initialize the mp variable `mp = new MediaPlayer()`

Comment: hey and thank you for the quick answer. sorry but i didn't understood how i suppose to build the code as you answered above. could you give me a  little sample of the code?